# Removing graphics card from Ubuntu Server

Tags: 22.04, gpu

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 Server installation on a PC repurposed as a NAS. I currently have a GPU installed, but once everything is working properly I was hoping to remove it completely. I know some motherboards won't POST without a GPU (mine is a X570 Gigabyte Aorus Master), but short of that, I somehow corrupted a previous server installation by simply swapping GPUs (putting the old one back in didn't save it) and had to reinstall. So my question is, what are the main considerations for removing the GPU from the computer? Should I do any driver removal/other housekeeping to prevent it from corrupting the OS? Thanks for reading.